# I want to make carousel with vue 3(Composition API) + typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I want to make a carousel with Vue 3 + typescript. But it is so hard for me.
Someone said you can make a carousel by **"vue-awesome-swiper"**. I tried to find a tutorial on this, but I didn't.
How to use this one???
or Is there any easy CSS framework with Vue 3 + typescript just like bootstrap, **"[vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/)"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is not much options you can choose.

The current `swiper` library supports Vue3 natively while lacking type definition but I think they will add it very soon.

Here is the codesandbox for demonstrating the use of swiper + vue3 + typescript

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-swiper-l3n0h?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

**Install swiper**

```
npm install swiper
// or
yarn add swiper
```

To bypass the type declaration error, you will need to add a `.d.ts` file to declare the swiper module suggested by one of the [GitHub user](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3916#issuecomment-818462663).

```
declare module "swiper/vue" {
  import { DefineComponent } from "vue";

  export const Swiper: DefineComponent<any, any, any>;
  export const SwiperSlide: DefineComponent<any, any, any>;
}
```

---

There is lots of example in swiper docs, you can play with it:

https://swiperjs.com/demos